# Find all singularities of the given function, classify them, calculate their residues

Tags: functions, residue-calculus

Function: $f(z)=-\frac{cos(z)}{(z+4i)z^2} $

I think necessary values are: $z=-4i;0$

Also they are both poles, or at least $z=0$ is, because the limit of: $$\lim \limits_{z \to 0} -\frac{cos(z)}{(z+4i)z^2}=\infty$$ but  how to know what order it is? And how to solve:
$$\lim \limits_{z \to -4i} -\frac{cos(z)}{(z+4i)z^2}$$

Am I at least doing this correctly? and how to calculate residues?
If it's not difficult, I would appreciate full step-by-step solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the order; following the definition of pole: $z_0$ is a $m$-th order pole for $f$ if and only if $$\lim_{z\to z_0}{(z-z_0)^mf(z)}=L\in \Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\},$$

and therefore you can prove $-4i$ is a first order pole, while $0$ is a second order pole.

Then for the residues you have a few options:

- Using the definition; if $f$ is a holomorphic function in $B_{\beta}(z_0)\setminus \bar{B}_{\alpha}(z_0)$, for $r \in (\alpha,\beta)$ the residue $Res(f, z_0)$ is the $-1$-th coefficient of the Laurent expansion series, i.e. 
  $$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B_r(z_0)}{\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz},\ n\in \Bbb{Z},$$
  are the coefficients of the series, and $B_r(z_0)$ is the complex ball of radius $r$ centered in $z_0$. This could be useful if you have some complex exponential function, for example.
- There is a particular case for order $m$ poles: 
  $$Res(f, z_0) = \lim_{z\to z_0}{\frac{1}{(m-1)!}[(z-z_0)^mf(z)]^{(m-1)}},$$
  where the last exponent **means a derivative** in $z$ rather than a power. This is very simple, especially for first order poles, and this would suit your case.

Given these piece of info the exercise should be simple. Keep working!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. A route may be to use Taylor series expansions, as $z \to 0$, 
$$
\begin{align}
\cos (z)&=1-\frac{z^2}2+O(z^3)
\\\frac{1}{(z+4i)}&=\frac{1}{4i}\frac{1}{\big(1+\frac{z}{4i}\big)}
\\&=\frac{1}{4i}\left(1-\frac{z}{4i}-\frac{z^2}{16}+O(z^3)\right)
\\&=\frac{1}{4i}+\frac{z}{16}-\frac{z^2}{64i}+O(z^3)
\end{align}
$$ then multiply out all factors,
$$
f(z)=-\frac{cos(z)}{(z+4i)z^2}=-\frac{1}{z^2}\cdot \cos (z) \cdot \frac1{(z+4i)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\lim \limits_{z \to -4i} |f(z)|= \infty$$

and

$$\lim \limits_{z \to 0} |f(z)|= \infty.$$

$f$ has in $-4 i$ a pol of order $1$, hence

$$ res(f; -4i)=\lim \limits_{z \to -4i}(z+4i)f(z)$$

$f$ has in $0$ a pol of order $2$, hence

$$ res(f; 0)=\lim \limits_{z \to 0} \frac{ \partial}{ \partial z}[z^2f(z)]$$